# Optional value returning nil with ?? operator

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert an optional string to a Double, but when I unwrap my value is not taken:

```
let currentSwimDistanceTravelled = defaults.string(forKey: "SwimTotal") ?? "0.0"
```

After this code is run currentSwimDistanceTravelled is assigned a String value of "" as opposed to "0.0".

Sorry if I've missed something basic here, but I thought ?? was the best way to unwrap an optional.

Comment: It seems that you already saved an empty string for that value. Since it's an empty string, it's not nil, so you won't get the "0.0".

Comment: the unwrapping is correct, it prints `"0.0"` if the left side is `nil`.

Comment: Rather save `Double` value and then use non-optional getter `double(forKey:)`

Comment: Got it, I was assigning a value of "" elsewhere so was being called as that rather than nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right side of `default operator ??` only executes if left side is `nil`. I think your left side is empty string `""` here. Try following:

```
var currentSwimDistanceTravelled = "0.0"
if let val = defaults.string(forKey: "SwimTotal"), val != "" {
    currentSwimDistanceTravelled = val
}
```